# My ajax doesn't call the method on the controller

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have an  on my index page(thymeleaft page), with a click to call a function in ajax and this ajax method to call a method in the controller, but the method in the controller is not called.

href:

```
<a href="#" th:onclick="'addproductcart('+${p.id}+')'"><span></span>Add</a>
```

ajax:

```
function addproductcart(id){
        
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "/addproductcart/"+id,
    success : function(result){
        $('#headsearchproduct').val(result.id);
    } 
});
```

};

controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/addproductcart/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Produtocarrinho> adicionarprodutocarrinho(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
      Produtocarrinho produtocarrinho = new Produtocarrinho();
      Produtos produto = produtoRepository.findById(id).get();
      produtocarrinho.setId(produto.getId());
      produtocarrinho.setFoto1min(produto.getFoto1min());
      produtocarrinho.setQuantidade("1");
      produtocarrinho.setValor(produto.getPrecoNovo());
      ResponseEntity<Produtocarrinho> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Produtocarrinho>(produtocarrinho, HttpStatus.OK);
      return responseEntity;        
    
    }
```

I had already made a method exactly like that on another page of this project and it worked very well, and I already debugged it and saw that it is not called the controller method, does anyone know where is wrong?

Comment: Did you check the HTML that Thymeleaf has generated in the browser? Can you try adding logging to your JavaScript function to see if the AJAX call is triggered from the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, the problem was in the spring security blocking this request